# Formidable in Nature

Tags: riddle

> My prefix can make you quite hungry, 2 ways.
>   My suffix is where you might sleep.
>   My infix a "perfect," a giver of praise -
>   Together, your price can be steep.

What am I?

Hint:

> You may not have experienced the meaning of first line, depending on your U.S. state of origin

Hint 2:

> The "price" you pay will not be in money - it will be incurred if you come across something with this *adjective*

Comment: Doesn't the hint suggest that the puzzle should be tagged [tag:knowledge] as well?

Comment: Together, your price will be steep, yeah houses cost a lot, you sleep there too

Comment: Well, everyone should know it - it's a common word. I just wanted to let people know that the first word may mean something a bit different to certain people based on prior experience

Comment: "*depending on your U.S. state of origin*" - er, I don't have one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you

> Potent

My prefix can make you quite hungry, 2 ways.

> Pot(cannabis) can make you hungry and the other one is cooking pot.

My suffix is where you might sleep.

> A tent

My infix a "perfect," a giver of praise

> A perfect ten!

Together, your price can be steep. + Hint 2

> If you consume or use something potent you either receive a very great effect or the worst effect of it. Either way, it's very strong.

Hint 1

> Depending on the us states, they might call cannabis differently(?). Also @El-guest mention that it's illegal to use cannabis in most of the US states, but legal in some (Cali or Alaska for example)

Comment: Also, r13(vfa'g vg vyyrtny va fbzr fgngrf ohg yrtny va bguref?)

Comment: @El-guest Thank you! That makes sense. I will add to the answer.

Comment: Indeed - I'd give you an up vote, but I'm at my daily limit. I'll come back tomorrow!

Answer (score 0):

Are you

> Pain?

My prefix can make you quite hungry, 2 ways.

> P, as in peas, are food. Pai also sounds like pie.

My suffix is where you might sleep.

> In, or inn.

My infix a "perfect," a giver of praise -

> An AI praises you in video games. It's also designed to perfectly imitate humans.

Together, your price will be steep.

> Pain is indeed the price.

Hint 1:

> Not sure at all why there'd be trouble understanding. Maybe how you pronounce things?

Hint 2:

> The price paid is blood, sweat, and tears, which constitutes pain.

Comment: Not what I was looking for, but I like your explanations!